# Google Compute Engine API - Error while trying to create new VM instance

Tags: php

I am trying to create a new VM instance on Compute Engine with a custom 500G disk. I'm using the following code:

```
$options = array(
  'name' => 'ti4', 
  'machine_type' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/' . $project . '/zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/f1-micro',
  'disks' => array(
      array(
          'type' => 'PERSISTENT',
          'boot' => true,
          'initializeParams' => array(
              'diskName' => 'ti4',
              'diskSizeGb' => 500,
              'sourceImage' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/' . $project . '/zones/us-central1-a/disks?sourceImage=' . urlencode('http://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20140619')
          )
      )
  ),
  'networkInterfaces' => array(
      array(
          'network' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/' . $project . '/global/networks/default'
      )
  ) 
);


$resource = $service->instances->insert($project, 'us-central1-a', new Google_Service_Compute_Instance($options), array());
```

And I'm getting the following error message:

```
...(400) Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/467549724285/zones/us-central1-a/disks?sourceImage=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fcompute%2Fv1%2Fprojects%2Fcentos-cloud%2Fglobal%2Fimages%2Fcentos-6-v20140619'. Must be the URL to a Compute resource of the correct type...
```

But according to [this](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#starting_an_instance_in_the_api) description, the sourceImage parameter is correct.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Try https for the sourceImage parameter so `urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20140619')`

Comment: I have the same problem, were you able to solve this?